# Start/stop a systemd service in cronjob

Tags: shell, cron, systemd

1. I have a service name bots in /etc/systemd/system/bots.service
2. I have a shell script name runcron.sh like this

> ```
> service bots stop
>
> service bots start
> ```

3. If I run ./runcron.sh the service will be stop then start successfully but if I put it in a crontab like this, it won't run successfully

> */5 * * * * /home/vps171-107/runcron.sh

How can I make runcron.sh stop then start the bots service in crontab ?

**UPDATE**

After the help from @armnotstrong , I've change the script to

```
/usr/sbin/service bots stop
/usr/sbin/service bots start
```

And it works!

Answer (score 4):

It may be an env issue, crontab may execute the command with `sh` not `bash` try:

```
*/5 * * * * bash /home/vps171-107/runcron.sh
```

Comment: `bash /home/vps171-107/runcron.sh>> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1` try to redirect the error log see what happened

Comment: it says /home/vps171-107/runcron.sh: line 2: service: command not found

Comment: if i change to /usr/sbin/service bots stop it works. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad could help :D

Comment: Can you please update your answer to change from 

service bots stop
service bots start

To 

/usr/sbin/service bots stop 
/usr/sbin/service bots start

So I can mark yours as accepted answer ?

Comment: You found the pit yourself. So you should answer the question yourself and take that as an answer :D